# how to push array in javascript by turns?

Tags: javascript

I have a code like this:

```js
const allData = []
const name = ["adit","aril","anni"]
const data = [{name : "adit", job: "employee"},{name : "aril", job: "employee"},{name : "anni", job: "employee"}]
```

I want to push `name` and `data` consecutively to `allData` like this:

```js
const allData = ["adit",{name : "adit", job: "employee"},"aril",{name : "aril", job: "employee"},"anni",{name : "anni", job: "employee"}]
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4642212). Use the available [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods) methods (both static and on prototype). This isn’t hard to achieve, so have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: What exactly are you aiming to get out of that structure? alternating between strings and objects doesn't seem particularly useful?

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+alternate+values+from+two+arrays) of [Merge two arrays with alternating values](/q/47061160/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const name = ["adit", "aril", "anni"]
const data = [{
  name: "adit",
  job: "employee"
}, {
  name: "aril",
  job: "employee"
}, {
  name: "anni",
  job: "employee"
}]

const concatArrays = (arr1, arr2) => {
  if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) throw new Error('Input arrays should have the same length')
  return arr1.reduce((r, v, i) => [...r, v, arr2[i]], [])
}

const allData = concatArrays(name, data)

console.log(allData)
```